# How to custom query in Cakephp 1.3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-1.3

I want to write some custom query in cakephp 1.3.17

I write the following in the function in the Users controller

```
$arrayTemp =array();
$arrayTemp = $this->Users->query('SELECT * FROM ht_users Where id=$id');
$this->set('post',$arrayTemp);
pr($post);
```

but its getting the following error in the page

```
Error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object    
File: D:\xamp\htdocs\devworks\app\Controller\UsersController.php    
Line: 1478
```

Line:1478 means it indicate -> $arrayTemp = $this->Users->query('SELECT * FROM ht_users Where id=$id ');

how I can execute a custome query here plz help

Comment: can you please let me know in user model have you define name in your model class ?

Comment: You need to use $this->User->query($sql) instead of $this->Users->query($sql). can you please try this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Your Model name is **User** so you need to write custom query as below.

```
$arrayTemp =array();
$id='1'; // For example. $id is whatever id you're receiving here
$arrayTemp = $this->User->query("SELECT * FROM ht_users Where id = '$id'");
$this->set('post',$arrayTemp);
```

Now you can pr($post) in your function.ctp file. If this code is written in index() function then try to print in index.ctp likewise.

Please try with above code, Let me know if still any issues.

Comment: Yes I have try code no error is coming here but it did not return any value in post but the query return value when I test it in mysql.
Its showing 
Undefined variable: post [APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 1484]

Answer (score 0):

As per Cakephp Conventions,

`Model class name are singular, this should be the database table name but in singular format.`

So,In your case it must be **User**

And then use below code

```
$arrayTemp =array();
$arrayTemp = $this->User->query('SELECT * FROM ht_users Where id=$id');
$this->set('post',$arrayTemp);
```